# conversion from timestamp to moment returning a day before

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a timestamp to a moment js object, like this:

```
let obj = moment.unix(1459382400);
```

It returns Wed Mar 30 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (CDT) which is wrong, because the given timestamp corresponds to Thu, 31 Mar 2016 00:00:00 GMT.

Am I missing something? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's because your timezone. Do moment.unix(1459382400).utc()

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: Be more specific.  What do you get when you try with utc

Comment: In the example I get the correct answer, in my code I get a day before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, momentjs is using your local timezone, so I guess there might be your problem. 
You can use `let obj = moment.unix(1459382400).utc();` instead, which should give you what you need.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/2544/

corresponding docs here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it keeps giving me back the wrong date.

Comment: The example in the fiddle returns the correct date, and this answer is correct.  @assembler you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I saw your example... it works there, but it doesn't work in my code.

Comment: @James, I know I'm missing something... can't find what

Comment: @assembler please then show more relating code, at best show a minimal complete example on jsfiddle. Might have something to do with some initial config of momentjs/dateobjects in your app, but seeing your code, this is the only thing I can think of right now. The momentjs-version u use would be good, too. And at last, have you tried cmd shift r (or the corresponding "DELETE MY CACHE"-Thing after changing the line? This might be the reason it didn't change, too.

Comment: Mr. @Dominik, the code is as simple as in the question. Now I have something else I'd like to add: I'm using it within a react-redux project. Also I took this code snippet out and placed it into a simple html file and it worked properly. So, I think there must be something related to react or redux that is conflicting with moment. I'm using moment 2.18.1 by the way.

Answer (score 5):

It is because of your timezone, do `.utc()` at the end.